# help with css formatting on table and div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have the following html (i'm also using Jquery and JqueryUI)

```
<div style="display:none; position:fixed; z-index:100;padding:0;margin:0" class="ui-state-highlight" id="Info">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding:0;margin:0">
            <tr style="padding:0;margin:0;">
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info"></span></td>
                <td width = "100%" style="padding:0;margin:0;"><div id = "InfoText"></div></td>
                <td><button style="width:25px;height:25px;margin:0;padding:0" id="closeInfo"></button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>            
    </div>
```

It procudes the following:

[image]

See where i circled in red? I want to get rid of that yellow space under the button, but i can't figure out how...

[image]

Thanks!

Solved:

```
<div style="display:none; position:fixed; z-index:100" class="ui-state-highlight" id="Info">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info"></span></td>
                    <td width = "100%"><div id = "InfoText"></div></td>
                    <td><button style="width:25px;height:25px;vertical-align:middle;display:block;" id="closeInfo"></button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
        </div>
```

Comment: I appoligize about the terrible pictures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an alignment issue, try:

```
<td valign="middle">  
  <button style="[...]; vertical-align:middle; display:block;"></button>
</td>
```

Comment: Oh no... This solution screws with the functionality of the button. I can only click on the borders of the button when using this solution.

Comment: It seems as though `displya:block;` is whats causing the button not to work. However, just `vertical-align:middle` fixes the problem. No need for `display:block`

Answer (score 0):

Include the applicable css file styles too.

With what you've given, I suggest:

```
<td width="100%;padding:0;"><div id ="InfoText"></div></td>
<td><button style="width:25px;height:25px;margin:0;" id="closeInfo"></button></td>
```

Comment: no other css sytles. I tried what you suggested, no change in effect